# Extract the numeric value from string in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kustomize, kusto-explorer

This is my datatable:

```
datatable(Id:dynamic)
[
    dynamic([987654321][Just Kusto Things]), 
]
```

and I've extracted 1 field from a json using

```
| project ID=parse_json(Data).["CustomValue"]
```

And the result is something like - **[987654321][Just Kusto Things]**. I wanted to extract the numbered value(987654321) within the 1st square brackets. How to best retrieve that value? Using split/parse/extract?

Answer (score 1):

the datatable in the sample is not valid. If the values are just an array then you can get the results by using the array position like this:

```
datatable(Id:dynamic)
[
    dynamic([987654321,"Just Kusto Things"]), 
]
| extend Id = Id[0]
```

If it is something else, please provide a valid datatable with an example that is representative of the real data.

Answer (score 0):

> *the result is something like - `[987654321][Just Kusto Things]`. I wanted to extract the numbered value(987654321) within the 1st square brackets. How to best retrieve that value?*

you can use the `parse` operator

For example:

```
print input = '[987654321][Just Kusto Things]'
| parse input with '[' output:long ']' *
```

Comment: Thanks this works! Is there a way I can use extract and also is there a thing to worry between parse and extract?

Comment: in this case, using `parse` would be more efficient than using `extract()` - as you don't need to use a regular expression